# What is the function you should use when you are trying to solve the particular solution to a trigonometry function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, trigonometry

Given $y ′′(t ) + y (t ) = \sin t$

I know that you use $y_{p} = tA \sin t + tB \cos t$

> but my question is why?
>
> Why can't I use

$y_{p} = A \sin t + B \cos t$

> or better

$y_{p} = A \sin (Bt + C) + D$?

Comment: Well, have you tried to insert your suggestions into the left-hand side of the ODE? They simply don't work; for no choice of the constants can you make the left-hand side match the given right-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark: The choice of particular solution shouldn't be any combination of solutions of complementary equation.

The given ODE is $\,\,\color{green}{\mathtt{{y}^{\prime\prime}(t)+y(t)=sin(t)}}$

We want a particular solution to the given ODE.

Let the particular solution of the given ODE be $\,\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{y}_{p}={u}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+{u}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)}}$

where, $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{\phi}_{1}\,,\,{\phi}_{2}}}\,$  are solutions of complementary equation of the given ODE.

We need to find the functions  $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}_{1}\,\,\&\,\,{u}_{2}}}\,$

Since $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{y}_{p}}}\,$ is a solution to the ODE, it must satisfy the given ODE

So, differentiating $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{y}_{p}}}\,$ w.r.t $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{t}}\,$, we get

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{y}^{\prime}_{p}(t)={u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+{u}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)+{u}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)}}$$

Again, differentiating $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{y}^{\prime}_{p}}}\,$ w.r.t $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{t}}\,$, we get

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{y}^{\prime\prime}_{p}(t)={u}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)+{u}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)}}$$

Put these in the given equation,

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{y}^{\prime\prime}_{p}(t)+y_{p}(t)=sin(t)}}$$

$$\color{brown}{\implies\mathtt{{u}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)+{u}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)+{u}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+{u}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)=sin(t)}}$$

$$\color{brown}{\implies\mathtt{{u}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}_{1}(t)\left({\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)+{\phi}_{1}(t)\right)+{u}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)+{u}_{2}(t)\left({\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)+{\phi}_{2}(t)\right)=sin(t)}}$$

Since, $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{\phi}_{1}\,,\,{\phi}_{2}}}\,$  are solutions of complementary equation of the given ODE, so, $\,\color{brown}{\mathtt{{\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)+{\phi}_{1}(t)=0\,\,\,\,\&\,\,\,\,{\phi}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)+{\phi}_{2}(t)=0}}\,$

$$\color{brown}{\implies\mathtt{{u}^{\prime\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}^{\prime\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)+2\,{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)=sin(t)}}$$

If $$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}_{1}^{\prime}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{1}(t)+{u}_{2}^{\prime}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)=0}}$$

Then $$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}_{1}^{\prime}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)+{u}_{2}^{\prime}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)=sin(t)}}$$

Solving these two equations, we get

$$\boxed{\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)=-\dfrac{{\phi}_{2}(t)\cdot sin(t)}{{\phi}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)-{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)}}}}$$

$$\boxed{\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)=\dfrac{{\phi}_{1}(t)\cdot sin(t)}{{\phi}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}^{\prime}_{2}(t)-{\phi}^{\prime}_{1}(t)\cdot{\phi}_{2}(t)}}}}$$

Now, for the given ODE,  $\color{green}{\mathtt{{\phi}_{1}(t)=cos(t)\,\,\,\,\&\,\,\,\,{\phi}_{2}(t)=sin(t)}}$

Putting these in above equations, we get,

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)=-\dfrac{sin(t)\cdot sin(t)}{cos(t)\cdot cos(t)+sin(t)\cdot sin(t)}}}$$

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)=\dfrac{cos(t)\cdot sin(t)}{cos(t)\cdot cos(t)+sin(t)\cdot sin(t)}}}$$

$\implies$

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}^{\prime}_{1}(t)=-sin^{2}(t)}}$$

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}^{\prime}_{2}(t)=sin(t)\,cos(t)}}$$

On integrating these two, we get,

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}_{1}(t)=-\dfrac{t}{2}+\dfrac{sin(2t)}{4}}}$$

$$\color{brown}{\mathtt{{u}_{2}(t)=-\dfrac{cos(2t)}{4}}}$$

Now, $\,\color{green}{\mathtt{{y}_{p}}}\,$ becomes,

$$\color{green}{\mathtt{{y}_{p}=\left\{-\dfrac{t}{2}+\dfrac{sin(2t)}{4}\right\}\cdot cos(t)+\left\{-\dfrac{cos(2t)}{4}\right\}\cdot sin(t)}}$$

$$\color{green}{\mathtt{\implies{y}_{p}=-\dfrac{t}{2}\cdot cos(t)+\dfrac{1}{4}\left\{sin(2t)cos(t)-cos(2t)sin(t)\right\}}}$$

$$\color{green}{\mathtt{\implies{y}_{p}=-\dfrac{t}{2}\cdot cos(t)+\dfrac{sin(t)}{4}}}$$

Since  $\color{blue}{\mathtt{sin(t)}}$  is a solution to complementary equation, so, we can't use it as a particular solution, so,

$$\color{green}{\mathtt{{y}_{p}=-\dfrac{t}{2}\cdot cos(t)}}$$